# How do I run systemctl restart apache2 in AWS Ubuntu when it requires a password

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, apache2

I am trying to restart Apache and I get...

```
ubuntu@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:~$ systemctl restart apache2
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'apache2.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
```

This is a brand new instance and I never set the ubuntu user password. Is there a default password set on instance creation?

How do I restart apache in AWS Ubuntu?

Comment: This is a very useful question. The fact that it's closed just shows that Stack Overflow is dumb.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you setup a key pair for your instance on creation, then there is no password for the user `ubuntu` nor is password based login enabled. You must login using your key pair.

To execute commands that require elevated permissions, use `sudo` in front of your command. The actual command to restart apache2 depends on which Linux distribution and version you are using.

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

or

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I was missing sudo and thats why it was asking for password.